# How to feed wordpress posts in a external website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog and a PHP website. I intend to feed the last 6 posts from that Wordpress blog to this PHP website. Taking the title, url and thumbnail, and all this from two specific post category. Can anyone help me the best and simple way to do that? I'm a front end developer and I'm not so good in PHP =/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use the built-in [rss feeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds).

Comment: I think its better to use WP API http://wp-api.org/ for better filtering, then use curl or file_get_content

Comment: Thanks guys! But you have some snippets as example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this method

1. Install [WP API](http://wp-api.org/)
2. Get the JSON URL of what you want to load, refer to [docs](http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts)

e.g. `http://yourdomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?filter[posts_per_page]=6&filter[orderby]=date`

3. Display data from JSON using file_get_content and json_decode

`$posts = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?filter[posts_per_page]=6&filter[orderby]=date'));
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    echo '<a href="'.$post->link.'">'.$post->title->rendered.'</a>';
}`

Comment: First, thank you so much! Second. Can you make a snippet that shows the thumbnail and two categories too? Thanks again!

Comment: sorry, I don't have development environment that has WP API installed, I can't really do any test, you can dump the ```$posts``` variable and you should be able to see the actual object output. e.g. ```echo '<pre>', print_r( $posts, 1), '</pre>';``` you can then include the thumbnail and categories key on the foreach output.

Answer (score 2):

There is plugins that can help you move the data from and to your WP site.. Check out this link about WP plugins and RSS feeds

http://mashable.com/2008/09/08/rss-plugins-for-wordpress/#haJPCZ7VPaqG

An Easy Way to Display an RSS Feed with PHP

The following code will first create a new DOMDocument() into which we will load the WordPress.org RSS feed.

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://wordpress.org/news/feed/');
```

Then we will single out certain elements and place them into an array. For this example, I will just fetch the title, description, link and published on date.

```
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
```

Finally, we set it to display 5 posts on screen with the titles linking directly to the original post.

```
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}
```

Not too complicated. All you need to change is the feed you want to load (line #3) and the number of posts to display (line #14). Of course, you could always play around with the output to get it styled exactly how you want. That is totally up to you.